# Retrieving data from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve data from sqlite but I don't know what's wrong with my code

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private String user,position;
    private DatabaseHelper helper;
    private List<User> user_position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        helper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
        if (helper.getUserlogin()==0) {
            finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class));
        }else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);

        user_position= helper.getUserPosition();
        user = String.valueOf(user_position.get(0).getUserName());
        position=String.valueOf(user_position.get(1).getUserPosition());
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
        textView.setText(user+"("+position+")");
    }
}
```

and this is the database reader method

```
public List<User> getUserPosition() {

        List<User> oList = new ArrayList<User>();

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(ORDER_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null,
                null);


            User user = new User();
            user.setUserName(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ROW_USER)));
            user.setUserPosition(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ROW_POSITION)));

            oList.add(user);

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();

        if (db != null)
            db.close();

        return oList;

    }
```

Comment: What is not working? What is expected result and whats you are getting?

Comment: Where are you initializing `helper`?

Comment: yes I will edit the question to more clear @Rohit5k2

Comment: I don't know why always the site giving error when i try to make edit

Comment: I have also this (helper=new DatabaseHelper(this);) inside onCreate

Comment: it showed this error

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amaiub.hussain.smartmenu/com.amaiub.hussain.smartmenu.MainPage}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: Please try my answer. See if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not looping through your cursor so there is no result in the returned array (Cursor starts before the first result and you haven't used `moveToFirst()` either).

Replace

```
User user = new User();
user.setUserName(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ROW_USER)));
user.setUserPosition(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ROW_POSITION)));
oList.add(user);
```

with

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserName(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ROW_USER)));
    user.setUserPosition(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ROW_POSITION)));
    oList.add(user);
}
```

**Update:** You are returning a list from DB

```
user_position = helper.getUserPosition();
if(user_position.size() > 0){
    User user = user_position.get(0);
    user = String.valueOf(user.getUserName());
    position=String.valueOf(user.getUserPosition());
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user);
    textView.setText(user+"("+position+")");
}
else
    Log.e("No user", "NO user found");
```

Comment: yes it show this error:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                  at com.amaiub.hussain.smartmenu.MainPage.onCreate(MainPage.java:91)

Comment: it's mean the problem in this lines:
user_position= helper.getUserPosition();
            user = String.valueOf(user_position.get(0).getUserName());
            position=String.valueOf(user_position.get(1).getUserPosition());

Comment: I tried edit the question I don't know why it's showed error so I add the full code in another answer

Comment: Remove the code after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);` and try to use code I have updated in `MainPage.java`. Also, please remove the answer you have posted.

Comment: thanks dear for help, the problem is fixed little bet, I retrieved the data, and I sure of that because I have some button if the position admin it will be visible else it will be invisible so it's work very good and it's the main reason for retrieve position, I make textview only for sure, but it confusing why can't display from sqlite to textview maybe because it's in navigation drawer.

Comment: I am sure we can display it in `TextView`. Can't point any reason without looking at the complete code. Also, if the issue is resolved please don't forget to accept the answer.